# Using a space for canceling a simple loop

Tags: c++

Here is my code for this simple assignment:

> Write the code that will read character input from the user until a blank (a space) is entered. Print how many characters were entered. Keep in mind the user may decide to enter a blank as his first character.

Why is the space not ending the loop?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
char answer;
int count=1;


do{
    cout << "please enter number " << count;
    cin >> answer;
    count++;

}while(answer!=' ');
    cout << "you entered " << count-1 << "numbers." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can just start `count` at 0 and print `count` instead of `count-1`.

Comment: Because `cin >>` skips whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cin >>` operations skip all kinds of whitespace by default. You can use [`cin >> noskipws;`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/) before your loop to disable whitespace skipping or use [`cin.get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) instead:

```
cin.get(answer);
```

You should be aware that newlines and carriage returns are no longer skipped now, so you have to handle them separately. Also, you should check the stream status to react to end-of-file:

```
do {
    cout << "Please enter number " << count << endl;
    do {
        cin.get(answer);
    } while (cin && (answer == '\r' || answer == '\n'));
    count++;
} while (cin && answer != ' ');
```

Comment: Okay, but actually.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
char answer;
int count=1;

cin >> noskipws;
do{
    cout << "please enter number " << count << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    count++;
}while(answer!=' ');
    cout << "you entered " << count-1 << "numbers." << endl;
    return 0;
}

I entered this in, like told. and it started like, double skipping.
"Please enter number"
Number entered 1
"please enter number 2
please enter number 3"
nubmer entered 3
"please enter number 3
Please enter number 4"
number entered  is space
"you entered 5 numbers"

Comment: @Dicey: I can only guess, but maybe your problem is that it now doesn't skip the newline character any longer. You should check for that separately.

Comment: @Dicey: Please check my edit. You can do the same with `cin >> answer` and `noskipws`.